# Comparing a list element with all others list's elements in search for equal values

Tags: python, pandas, list, compare

I have a LIST with 240 time series.
two pairs in that list are EQUAL, let's suppose list[4] is equal to list[36] and list[105] is equal to list[208]
let's also suppose I don't know that these pairs are equal. How can I check it in my code?

if I do list[4] == list[36] it'll return a series with True values and that's the only way I can think of verifying this. So I guess I'll have to do something like:
list[1] == list[ i ] (all lists expect list[1]) and if it finds a TRUE value, it'll mark them as equal, them list[2] == list[i] (except list[2]), and so on

Comment: do you have to know the indices, or just know if a duplicate exists?

Comment: please provide a sample input as well as your desired output

Comment: I want to know if a >value< is duplicated. if one or more values are duplicated then I can assume both lists [a] and [b] are equal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will give you a list of lists, the values being the indices of matching lists:

```
_LIST = [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [1, 2], ['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd'], [5, 6]]

res = []
for i, v in enumerate(_LIST):
    idxs = [idx + i for idx, val in enumerate(_LIST[i:]) if v == val]
    if len(idxs) > 1:
        res.append(idxs)

print(res)
```

```
[[0, 3], [2, 6]]
```

Alternatively, you can use the `.index()` method like so:

```
_LIST = [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [1, 2], ['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd'], [5, 6]]

res = []
for i, v in enumerate(_LIST):
    try:
        dup_idx = _LIST[i+1:].index(v) + i + 1
        res.append([i, dup_idx])
    except ValueError: # pass up unique lists, throws ValueError because dup_idx doesn't exist
        pass

print(res)
```

```
[[0, 3], [2, 6]]
```